# After showing Toast message and How to avoid calling the server side controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have comparison quote object.In that ***comparison quotes "selected" check box is true means user need to fill "Business Type".***

In that ***comparison quotes "selected" check box is false means user no  need to fill "Business Type". (He can save comparison Quotes)***

I had written this validation in Lightning component.I have save method

jAVASCRIPT CONTROLLER:

```
   save : function(component, event, helper) {
   helper.saveComparisonQuotes(component, event, helper);
    var action = component.get("c.saveDispositionOpportunity");
    //SAVING DISPOSITION
   }
.......

 saveComparisonQuotes:function(component,event,helper) {
 var comparisonQuotes=component.get("v.ComparisonQuotes")
      for(var i=0;i<comparisonQuotes.length;i++){
        if(comparisonQuotes[i].Selected__c==true){
            if(comparisonQuotes[i].Business_Type__c==null ||comparisonQuotes[i].Business_Type__c=='' ){
              var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                    toastEvent.setParams({
                        title : 'Error Message',
                        message:'Buisness Type is mandatory for selected Quotes',
                        duration:' 5000',
                        key: 'info_alt',
                        type: 'error',
                        mode: 'pester'
                    });
                    toastEvent.fire();
                 }
  var action = component.get("c.saveComparisonQuotes");
    action.setParams({
        "ListComparison": component.get("v.ComparisonQuotes")
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.errors", 'ComparisonQuotes saved.');
            $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);            
}
}
```

---

Here what I need after getting toast message "saveComparisonQuotes" should not call (user has to enter Business Type).But now it calling.(its wrong)
and In case of error in "SaveComparison Quotes" and "Disposition record should not create".

***Observed Behaviour:***

- saveComparisonQuotes is calling and after showing toast message
- Disposition record also saving

***Expected Behaviour:***

- After showing toast message,comparison quote "saveComparisonQuotes" method 
     should not call.

  - Disposition record should not create (saveDispositionOpportunity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Boolean variable to control the functionality.

```
saveComparisonQuotes:function(component,event,helper) {
   var comparisonQuotes=component.get("v.ComparisonQuotes"); 
   var isValid = true;
   for(var i=0;i<comparisonQuotes.length;i++){ 
     if(comparisonQuotes[i].Selected__c==true){
       if(comparisonQuotes[i].Business_Type__c==null 
         ||comparisonQuotes[i].Business_Type__c=='' ){
           isValid = false;
           var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
           toastEvent.setParams({
             title : 'Error Message',
             message:'Buisness Type is mandatory for selected Quotes',
             duration:' 5000',
             key: 'info_alt',
             type: 'error',
             mode: 'pester'
           });
           toastEvent.fire();
       }
       if(isValid) {
         var action = component.get("c.saveComparisonQuotes");
         action.setParams({
          "ListComparison": component.get("v.ComparisonQuotes")
         });
         action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
           var state = response.getState();
           if (state === "SUCCESS") {
             component.set("v.errors", 'ComparisonQuotes saved.');
             $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
           }
         });
         $A.enqueueAction(action);            
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Ya.I got it!!..even I thought about variable count.anyway same logic.wil apply for my second question as well.okay ill go for boolean variable solution.Thanks